How to update the Status column via the Notion API？
I referred to the example in the Status section of the documentation https://developers.notion.com/reference/property-value-object#status-property-values and write a http post request to add a row in a database,the json of the post is:
{
  "parent": {
    "database_id": "52bda5d8b8b84220826d701e4415cfd0"
  },
  "properties": {
    "Name": {
      "type": "title",
      "title": [
        {
          "type": "text",
          "text": {
            "content": "Gain"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    "Gold": {
      "number": 1
    },
    "Status": {
      "status": {
        "name": "Done"
      }
    },
    "Due": {
      "date": {
        "start": "2024-11-01 16:41:57"
      }
    },
    "Gold": {
      "relation": [
        {
          "id": "f56673926da14bf8b0452243a6b2fedb"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}

but I still get the following error when updating:
{
  "object": "error",
  "status": 400,
  "code": "validation_error",
  "message": "body failed validation. Fix one:\nbody.properties.Status.title should be defined, instead was `undefined`.\nbody.properties.Status.rich_text should be defined, instead was `undefined`.\nbody.properties.Status.number should be defined, instead was `undefined`.\nbody.properties.Status.url should be defined, instead was `undefined`.\nbody.properties.Status.select should be defined, instead was `undefined`.\nbody.properties.Status.multi_select should be defined, instead was `undefined`.\nbody.properties.Status.people should be defined, instead was `undefined`.\nbody.properties.Status.email should be defined, instead was `undefined`.\nbody.properties.Status.phone_number should be defined, instead was `undefined`.\nbody.properties.Status.date should be defined, instead was `undefined`.\nbody.properties.Status.checkbox should be defined, instead was `undefined`.\nbody.properties.Status.relation should be defined, instead was `undefined`.\nbody.properties.Status.files should be defined, instead was `undefined`.\nbody.properties.Status.status should be defined, instead was `undefined`.\nbody.properties.Name.id should be defined, instead was `undefined`.\nbody.properties.Name.name should be defined, instead was `undefined`.\nbody.properties.Name.start should be defined, instead was `undefined`.",
  "request_id": "e95533bc-f3a2-4a6a-a6e7-aacbd0f59787"
}

